# Collision Monitor in Nav2 not work

Tags: nav2, collision

I am new to using Collision Monitor in Nav2 package. I am wondering how to make it worked because I can launch the default launch file and my yaml file is as the following

```
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    base_frame_id: "robot_base_footprint"
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    cmd_vel_in_topic: "cmd_vel_raw"
    cmd_vel_out_topic: "diffbot_base_controller/cmd_vel_unstamped"
    transform_tolerance: 0.5
    source_timeout: 5.0
    stop_pub_timeout: 2.0
    # Polygons represent zone around the robot for "stop" and "slowdown" action types,
    # and robot footprint for "approach" action type.
    # Footprint could be "polygon" type with dynamically set footprint from footprint_topic
    # or "circle" type with static footprint set by radius. "footprint_topic" parameter
    # to be ignored in circular case.
    polygons: ["PolygonStop"]
    PolygonStop:
      type: "polygon"
      points: [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, -0.3, 0.0, -0.3, 0.0, 0.3]
      action_type: "stop"
      max_points: 3
      visualize: True
      polygon_pub_topic: "polygon_stop"
    PolygonSlow:
      type: "polygon"
      points: [0.4, 0.4, 0.4, -0.4, -0.4, -0.4, -0.4, 0.4]
      action_type: "slowdown"
      max_points: 3
      slowdown_ratio: 0.3
      visualize: True
      polygon_pub_topic: "polygon_slowdown"
    FootprintApproach:
      type: "polygon"
      action_type: "approach"
      footprint_topic: "/local_costmap/published_footprint"
      time_before_collision: 2.0
      simulation_time_step: 0.1
      max_points: 5
      visualize: False
    observation_sources: ["scan"]
    scan:
      type: "scan"
      topic: "/scan"
    pointcloud:
      type: "pointcloud"
      topic: "/intel_realsense_r200_depth/points"
      min_height: 0.1
      max_height: 0.5
```

However, in Rviz I cannot see the collision polygon (red).
Not sure if I missed something here.
Here is the tutorial I followed https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/using_collision_monitor.html#collision-monitor-tutorial

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   points: [0.4, 0.4, 0.4, -0.4, -0.4, -0.4, -0.4, 0.4]
> ```

This is not the format of the points in the tutorial you linked to

> points: "[[0.6, 0.4], [0.6, -0.4], [0.0, -0.4], [0.0, 0.4]]"

I'm guessing you have alot of error messages in your logs that you're not reading. I'd recommend looking through the logs carefully when something does not work as you might expect. We have alot of error messages and useful context in there.

Comment: I followed the tutorial and used that points format. However it's not allowed me to do so like in this output ```
[collision_monitor-1] [ERROR] [1708621702.748142324] [collision_monitor]: [PolygonStop]: Error while getting polygon parameters: parameter 'PolygonStop.points' has invalid type: Wrong parameter type, parameter {PolygonStop.points} is of type {double_array}, setting it to {string} is not allowed.```